# How do I import and call linphone_core_get_calls in vb?

Tags: vb.net, linphone-sdk

The API reference in question is located [here](http://linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__call__control.html#gaa25d228a47a97dd44d5ff4d1e4d4d5ba).

I need to know how to properly DLLImport and then use this in vb:

```
const bctbx_list_t* linphone_core_get_calls (   LinphoneCore *  lc  )
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the `const bctbx_list_t*` return value.  I tried declaring the dllimport like this:

```
<DllImport(LIBNAME, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function linphone_core_get_calls(lc As IntPtr) As List(Of IntPtr)
End Function
```

and then using it like this:

```
Dim CurrentCallList As List(Of IntPtr) = linphone_core_get_calls(_LinPhoneCore)
```

which compiles but gives me an error:

> Cannot marshal 'return value': Generic types cannot be marshaled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think `bctbx_list_t` is the same as .NET's `List`? It's almost certainly not; find where the `bctbx_list_t` type is defined and see how to better declare it. If it's an opaque object, declare it as `IntPtr`.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on GSerg's comment, I went looking for the definition of bctbx_list_t, which I found [here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/bctoolbox/blob/master/include/bctoolbox/list.h).  It's a linked list:

```
typedef struct _bctbx_list {
    struct _bctbx_list *next;
    struct _bctbx_list *prev;
    void *data;
} bctbx_list_t;
```

I translated that to:

```
Private Structure _bctbx_list
    Public [next] As IntPtr
    Public prev As IntPtr
    Public data As IntPtr
End Structure
```

changing the import to:

```
<DllImport(LIBNAME, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function linphone_core_get_calls(lc As IntPtr) As _bctbx_list
End Function
```

And I'm in business.